# In a multi-threaded application, which concurrency pattern is faster/better, "half-sync/half-async" or "leader/follower"?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, performance, concurrency

Hypothetically, lets say there two identical multi-threaded C/C++ applications (using pthread.h) under heavy load (thousands of requests per second) with 1 difference. One is using the half-sync/half-async concurrency pattern and the other leader/follower (same # of threads). Due to their relative similarity I've found myself asking a lot of questions with answers few and far in-between.

Is one generally faster than the other? Better? Are there specific cases where one should be used over the other? Is one considered "the norm" while the other is outdated?

I'm basically looking for insight here into why, when building a new multi-threaded application, I should plan to use one concurrency pattern over the other.

Comment: Mmmm... Ring buffer? Mutex?

Comment: which tech stack are we talking about? e.g. in .net you have so many classes/libs available that you don't need to implement them yourselves?

Comment: @MartinMoser specifically pthread.h I'm implementing in C/C++. I'll edit the question

Comment: Given nonblocking sockets, I'd consider both of them hilariously superfluous academic knick-knack on pretty much every "normal" server application. Stuff like completion callbacks seems super cool, but it can be a source of pain when they come from another thread. "Asynchronous service layer and advanced queueing system" are nice buzzwords for a sales pitch that makes you feel like a big boy, but "one network thread, a ring buffer, and a worker pool" is just as good.

Comment: @Damon Given a network thread, ring buffer and worker pool, wouldn't that pretty much be an implementation of a half-sync/half-async concurrency pattern? The network thread the synchronous part and the worker pool asynchronous? Is that the norm?

Comment: The network thread, too, is asynchronous (it's only synchronous when it blocks in `select` or `epoll` or `kqueue` or such, to conserve CPU). You will normally have all your sockets non-blocking and only read from them when they're ready (you need both, since they may become spuriously ready on some systems under some weird conditions, so they _would block_). Every receive is "instantaneous" (either successful or a failure), nothing runs synchronously. Under Windows you further have the "overlapped+iocp" alternative, which, too, is asynchronous, and basically the exact opposite way of doing it.

Comment: A single receiver thread has no trouble serving a few thousand requests per second, with either method (limited by bandwidth, of course... there's only so and so much you can physically push through a network cable).

Comment: @Damon Makes sense. In your opinion, when using non blocking sockets is it best to have threads dedicated to reading the sockets when they're marked as live? In the implementations I've made I usually use `select()` to create a list of live sockets which I iterate over and read from. After getting comfortable with pthreads I'm looking back and trying to see where I could improve the performance of a lot of past code.

Comment: @Damon Thank you for all you help. And I hope this issue is a purely academic one and I won't have to lose sleep over it after college. Unfortunately however, I am still here and am hoping someone will be able to answer this question.

Comment: You _can_ use several receivers, but I advise against it. 10G ethernet has a theoretical maximum throughput (using maximum frame sizes) of 1.24GiB/s. Typical single-thread `memcpy` speeds are 10-20 times as much, so there is not much of a challenge for a single thread receiving. On the other hand, partial receives are a possibility with TCP (so you must aggregate requests), and as soon as several threads get involved concurrently, this is getting ugly. For UDP, on the other hand, some operating systems (e.g. Linux) explicitly support single-syscall-multiple-receives, which pretty much give...

Comment: ... the maximum throughput that is physically possible, with minimum overhead. All with a single thread. See [recvmmsg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html). Adding threads to that will add complexity (and error proneness) but will not add value.